# Context menu not showing

Tags: javascript

I have a strange Javascript issue.

This code is supposed to show a context menu, but doesn't:

```
$find('RCMUNIT').showAt(document.getElementById('X').value, document.getElementById('Y').value);
```

but if I add an alert box to it, the menu shows, as does the alert box:

```
$find('RCMUNIT').showAt(document.getElementById('X').value, document.getElementById('Y').value);alert('x');
```

Comment: what library are you using?

Comment: @Henkemota what values are in X and Y elements? maybe decimal? could you show more code?

Comment: integers, like for example 112 and 145

Comment: try to set timeout of 1 or 2 sec then check whether Context menu is showing or not

Comment: That did the trick, thanks.

Code now looks like this:

setTimeout(""$find('RCMUNIT').showAt(document.getElementById('X').value, document.getElementById('Y').value);"",10);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not totally sure, but I'll believe that you should use setTimeout and it will work:

```
function showMenu()
{
 $find('RCMUNIT').showAt(document.getElementById('X').value,        document.getElementById('Y').value);
}

setTimeout('showMenu()',500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Code now looks like this and it works

setTimeout(""$find('RCMUNIT').showAt(document.getElementById('X').value, document.getElementById('Y').value);"",10);